# Issues with mysqli::prepare() and bind_param()

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have the following classes in my application:

```
    <?php

    class Connection extends Mysqli{

public function __construct($mysqli_host,$mysqli_user,$mysqli_pass, $mysqli_db) {
    parent::__construct($mysqli_host,$mysqli_user,$mysqli_pass,$mysqli_db);
    $this->throwConnectionExceptionOnConnectionError();     
}

private function throwConnectionExceptionOnConnectionError(){

    if(!$this->connect_error){
        echo "Database connection established<br/>";
    }else{
    //$message = sprintf('(%s) %s', $this->connect_errno, $this->connect_error);
        echo "Error connecting to the database."; 
    throw new DatabaseException($message);
    }
}
    }

    class DatabaseException extends Exception
    {
    }

class Page extends Mysqli{

private $con; 

public function __construct(Connection $con) {
    $this->con = $con;
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    }else{      
    $id = 1;
    }       
    $this->get_headers($id);
    $this->get_content($id);
    $this->get_footer($id);
}

private function get_headers($pageId){ 
    $retrieveHead = $this->con->prepare("SELECT headers FROM pages WHERE page_id=?");
    $retrieveHead->bind_param('i',$pageId);
    $retrieveHead->execute();
    $retrieveHead->bind_result($header);
    $retrieveHead->fetch();
    $retrieveHead->close();
    echo $header;   
}

private function get_footer($pageId){ 
    $retrieveFooter = $this->con->prepare("SELECT footer FROM pages WHERE page_id=?");
    $retrieveFooter->bind_param('i',$pageId);
    $retrieveFooter->execute();
    $retrieveFooter->bind_result($footer);
    $retrieveFooter->fetch();
    $retrieveFooter->close();
    echo $footer;   
}

private function get_content($pageId){
    $retreiveContent = $this->con->prepare("SELECT template_id, section_title, i1, i2 FROM content WHERE page_id=? ORDER BY sequence DESC");
    $retreiveContent->bind_param('i',$pageId);
    $retreiveContent->execute();
    $retreiveContent->bind_result($template_id, $section_title, $i1, $i2);
         while ($retreiveContent->fetch()) {
            //Variables will be populated for this row.
            //Update the tags in the template.
            $template = $this->get_template($template_id);
            $template = str_replace('[i1]',$i1,$template);
            $template = str_replace('[i2]',$i2,$template);
            //$theTemplate is populated with content. Probably want to echo here
            echo $template;
        }
}

private function get_template($template_id){
    $retreiveTemplate = $this->con->prepare("SELECT code FROM templates WHERE template_id=?");
    $retreiveTemplate->bind_param('i',$template_id);
    $retreiveTemplate->execute();
    $retreiveTemplate->bind_result($template);
    $retreiveTemplate->fetch();
    $retreiveTemplate->close();
    return $template;
}

}
    ?>
```

The small application should basically get the page variable from the url and use it to pull out the header, content items and footer of the page with the content items being rendered using a template which is also retreived from the database. When running my index file which contains the following code:

```
    require ("/req/db_connection.php");
    require ("/req/connection.php");
    $dbConnection = new Connection($mysqli_host,$mysqli_user,$mysqli_pass, $mysqli_db);
    $page = new Page();
```

I get the following output:

```
    Database connection established

    Warning: mysqli::prepare(): Couldn't fetch Page in C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\req\connection.php on line 39

    Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\req\connection.php on line 40
```

Could anyone point in the right direction as to why I am experiencing these errors?

Line 39 is the following statement:

```
     $retrieveHead = $this->prepare("SELECT headers FROM pages WHERE page_id=?");
```

And line 40 is of course:

```
     $retrieveHead->bind_param('i',$pageId);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

N.B. The code above has now been corrected based on the answers below however I am still experiencing the following error at line 80:

```
    Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\req\connection.php on line 80
```

Which is this line:

```
    $retreiveTemplate->bind_param('i',$template_id);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `SELECT 'headers' FROM pages WHERE ...` you have single quotes around your column name.

Comment: I don't know why that's in there. In my actual code that is absent so that is not the issue.

Comment: on a tangential note, your function names remind me of namespace hell in commercial environments, e.g. `Company.Subsidiary.Team.Project.Namespace.Class.someone_forgot_to_use_using`. Oh, and you have an extra `}` in there.

Comment: Hi Hiroto, this is just my attempt at getting back into PHP. It's not a commercial project (yet) and I'm just starting with the OOP approach so I don't really care about namespacing or anything like that just yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Page extends Mysqli{
public function __construct() {
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    }else{      
    $id = 1;
    }       
    $this->get_headers($id);
    $this->get_content($id);
    $this->get_footer($id);
}
```

This code above looks like the problem (amongst others). You extend mysqli, override the constructor and do not call the parent constructor. As a result none of the base mysqli constructor routines are invoked and you are left with no connection. Consider redesigning your objects and pass them your `Connection` object as opposed to extending mysqli everywhere. I'd also try to avoid doing all that work in the constructor. For example your page class could look something like:

```
class Page{

private $con;

public function __construct(Connection $con) {
    $this->con = $con;
}

public function get_headers($pageId){ 
    $retrieveHead = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT headers FROM pages WHERE page_id=?");
    //...
}

}
```

When I quipped "amongst others" (no discouragement intended) above I was hinting that -- while the actual cause of your error was the constructor -- there looks to be some confusion in the design of your classes and of OOP concepts in general.

```
class Connection extends Mysqli{

 public function __construct($mysqli_host,$mysqli_user,$mysqli_pass, $mysqli_db) {
    parent::__construct($mysqli_host,$mysqli_user,$mysqli_pass,$mysqli_db);
    $this->throwConnectionExceptionOnConnectionError();     
 }
}
```

Here you have extended `mysqli` with your `Connection` class, and correctly called the parent constructor and passed all the required parameters to establish a connection. If you instantiate an object of this type `$myConnection = new Connection(...)` it can act as your gateway to the database.

Other classes like `Page` may need to perform operations on the database and they can do it via `Connection` not by extending `mysqli` itself. You can pass an instance of `Connection` in the `Page` constructor to achieve this. So your lines of code here:

```
$dbConnection = new Connection($mysqli_host,$mysqli_user,$mysqli_pass, $mysqli_db);
$page = new Page();
```

Would become (after some modification to Page class like shown above):

```
$dbConnection = new Connection($mysqli_host,$mysqli_user,$mysqli_pass, $mysqli_db);
$page = new Page($dbConnection);
```

Comment: Amongst others? Please elaborate. Remember I am just starting out with the object orientated approach (I did it in Java in the first year of Uni but then focused on procedural PHP). I actually thought that the connection was the problem but was told elsewhere on here that extending mysqli or indeed the Connection object would solve my problem. How would I go about passing my objects the Connection object?

Comment: Apologies. OOP generally seems quite stupid in a lot of the approaches especially with regards to separation of concerns. If a database connection object is active it should allow access to all other classes to prevent the need for having to call the database object in every class (code for the sake of code). I've always struggled with OOP because a lot of it seems pointless when compared to how the same approach can be achieved with much fewer lines of code using procedural methodology.

Comment: Okay so i've ammended my code as above and the header is being output however I'm still getting an error at line 80: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Comment: @jme, you're making progress. If you're failing at `bind_param()` your connection is ok, but check that the SQL is ok in `prepare()`. I have removed the copy and paste single quotes if around 'header' if that threw you off.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the SQL query. SELECT code FROM templates WHERE template_id=?

Comment: I've even done a vardump on $template_id and it's value is int(1) so that's working correctly. I don't see how this query can be any different from the others.

Comment: @jme1988 Try `echo $this->con->error` immediately before `bind_param()` to see if you have problem generating `mysqli_stmt`.

Comment: It says: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Comment: It says: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Comment: @jme1988 All I can suggest is to step through and do some debugging. It is difficult to do without seeing your code in it's entirity and this isn't really the place for it. Try `$stmt = $this->con->stmt_init(); $stmt->prepare($yourQuery); echo $stmt->error;` in place of your prepare() line.

Comment: I have tried debugging. The fact is my query is no different to the others and I don't see why it isn't working. It's no different. The only difference is this function is called within another function whereas the others are called directly in the constructor.

Comment: Please see this new question for the call to a member_function error solution: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14718620/1110621

Answer (score 1):

This error message shows up because you haven't established a connection to the database server when you attempt to prepare the statement. A shorter reproduce code:

```
class Page extends Mysqli{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->prepare('SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP');
    }
}
new Page;
```

In mysql objects the connection is established in the [constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) but you override such constructor and never call the parent one.

IMHO, it makes little sense that pages are instances of the database object. You should simply provide a DB object as parameter when required.

**Update:**

You can pass the DB object every time you need it:

```
class Page{
    public function foo(Mysqli $db){
        $db->prepare('SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP');
    }
}
```

... or store it for later usage:

```
class Page{
    protected $db;
    public function __construct(Mysqli $db){
        $this->db = $db;
    }
    public function foo(){
        $this->db->prepare('SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP');
    }
}
```

If you extend `Mysqli`, use the correct class name as type hint:

```
public function foo(Connection $db){
}
```

There're other solutions like interfaces but it gets too complicate :)

Comment: And how would I go about providing a database object as a parameter (remember I'm a veteran of procedural PHP and I'm just starting with OOPHP.

Comment: @jme1988 - I've added a couple of examples.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this when I get home this evening. If it works then I'll mark your response as correct as you provided all of the information required.