# Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object not working inside function called from another function

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm receiving the error above in the get_template() function of my class listed below. Does anyone know why I am receiveing this error? All of the other queries execute fine and $template_number is definitely returning an int which is expected at this point in the query so why am I receiving this error? Could it be because the return on this query is formatted as TEXT in MySQL (and appears as a BLOB in PHPMyAdmin?

```
    class Page{

private $con; 

public function __construct(Connection $con) {
    $this->con = $con;
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    }else{      
    $id = 1;
    }       
    $this->get_headers($id);
    $this->get_content($id);
    $this->get_footer($id);
}

private function get_headers($pageId){ 
    $retrieveHead = $this->con->prepare("SELECT headers FROM pages WHERE page_id=?");
    $retrieveHead->bind_param('i',$pageId);
    $retrieveHead->execute();
    $retrieveHead->bind_result($header);
    $retrieveHead->fetch();
    $retrieveHead->close();
    echo $header;   
}

private function get_footer($pageId){ 
    $retrieveFooter = $this->con->prepare("SELECT footer FROM pages WHERE page_id=?");
    $retrieveFooter->bind_param('i',$pageId);
    $retrieveFooter->execute();
    $retrieveFooter->bind_result($footer);
    $retrieveFooter->fetch();
    $retrieveFooter->close();
    echo $footer;   
}

private function get_content($pageId){
    $retreiveContent = $this->con->prepare("SELECT template_id, section_title, i1, i2 FROM content WHERE page_id=? ORDER BY sequence DESC");
    $retreiveContent->bind_param('i',$pageId);
    $retreiveContent->execute();
    $retreiveContent->bind_result($template_id, $section_title, $i1, $i2);
         while ($retreiveContent->fetch()) {
            //Variables will be populated for this row.
            //Update the tags in the template.
            $template = $this->get_template($template_id);
            $template = str_replace('[i1]',$i1,$template);
            $template = str_replace('[i2]',$i2,$template);
            //$theTemplate is populated with content. Probably want to echo here
            echo $template;
        }
    $retreiveContent->close();
}

private function get_template($template_number){
    $retreiveFunction = $this->con->prepare("SELECT code FROM templates WHERE template_id=?");
    $retreiveFunction->bind_param('i',$template_number);
    $retreiveFunction->execute();
    $retreiveFunction->bind_result($template);
    $retreiveFunction->fetch();
    $retreiveFunction->close();
    return $template;
}

}
```

Table structure can be found below:

[image: Table Structure]

Comment: most of the time you can assume `Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object` is because you are calling `->bind_param` on `false` because the prepare failed. I'm assuming it is because of `$this->con`. You should implement mysqli, not pass the class in.

Comment: It works for all the other queries in the other functions so this is not the issue.

Comment: The error includes a line number, which unfortunately you have not provided. Go to that line and `var_dump` whatever it is that you are calling `bind_param` on. The rest will debug itself.

Comment: Ive already said ive done that before. Int(1) is returned which is what is expected.

Comment: Could it be to do with the fact that this function is called by the getContent function before the initial mySQLi query in getContent is closed? This would therefore cause a conflict...

Comment: Removed [oop], because putting something in a class doesn't make it OOP by magic.

Comment: @PeeHaa And what do you mean by that? It's obviously not procedural and demonstrates inheritence so it should be marked as OOP.

Comment: Class oriented programming

Comment: No it's object orientated as it uses objects!

Comment: Sure. Owkay. You may call it OOP. Let's also call JavaScript an OOP language in that case because it is freaking loaded with objects. Also even if it would have been OOP it has nothing to do with you question *at all*.

Comment: What's the point in downvoting a perfectly reasonable question? This uses the principles of object orientated programming. If you were to convince me otherwise with an actual explanation rather than just making statements then I may accept your edit.

Comment: @jme1988 Saying that your code is OOP because it uses classes is like saying that your car is a turbo model because it has a spoiler.

Comment: @PeeHaa Also I think you'll find that most newbies trying to learn object-orientated php will likely search for a solution such as this within the oop tag hence why it is marked in such a way. Furthermore as class orientated programming is a form of object orientated programming the tag still applies : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class-based_programming#Critique_of_class-based_models

Comment: @jme1988 You are completely wrong and this code violates numerous OOP principles. As a result of that, I hope that no newbies attempt to use this as a means of learning OOP, as they will be learning an invalid programming paradigm if they use what you have here as an example. Read up on the single responsibility principle and the other components of SOLID, and perhaps get a book on design patterns.

Comment: @Lusitanian How so when most of the basis of this code has come from official php sources. Why does it violate OOP principles? Provide examples. Nice to see someone else downvoting a perfectly valid question just because they don't like what they see in the comments.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For anyone else searching for this solution, as bwewsing suggests I needed to add in store_result however from the links provided above it's not too clear where this should be implemented.

Implementation should take place in the initial calling method. So, as the get_content() method calls the get_template() method it should be implemented here in the following manner:

```
    private function get_content($pageId){
    $retreiveContent = $this->con->prepare("SELECT template_id, section_title, i1, i2 FROM content WHERE page_id=? ORDER BY sequence DESC");
    $retreiveContent->bind_param('i',$pageId);
    $retreiveContent->execute();
    $retreiveContent->bind_result($template_id, $section_title, $i1, $i2);
    $retreiveContent->store_result();
         while ($retreiveContent->fetch()) {
            //Variables will be populated for this row.
            //Update the tags in the template.
            $template = $this->get_template($template_id);
            $template = str_replace('[i1]',$i1,$template);
            $template = str_replace('[i2]',$i2,$template);
            //$theTemplate is populated with content. Probably want to echo here
            echo $template;
        }
    $retreiveContent->free_result();    
    $retreiveContent->close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) and [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php). `mysqli_stmt::execute()` by default stores the results server side and fetches row by row unless you call `mysqli_stmt::store_result()` to buffer them client side. Attempting to prepare another statement most likely fails while there are unfetched reults server side from a previous statement.